# cURL, how to add this specific parameter?

Tags: php, api, curl, sendinblue

I have to create a PHP script that will create new contact in my sendinblue database. Sendinblue has an API that includes a PHP code generator to accomplish this. The documentation is located at: https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createcontact

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"email\":\"testCreateContact@test.com\",\"emailBlacklisted\":true,\"smsBlacklisted\":false,\"listIds\":[2],\"updateEnabled\":true}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "api-key: *****",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Now im looking for how to send the `attributes` field with the POST request, because you can't add `attributes` in the code creator on the documentation page:[image]

So I don't understand the syntax to include the `attributes` field in my code. Thanks!

EDIT :
So now ive tried this part of code :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'email' => 'testCreateContact@test.com',
    'emailBlacklisted' => true,
    'smsBlacklisted' => false,
    'listIds' => [2],
    'updateEnabled' => true,
    'attributes' => json_encode([
        "FNAME" => "Elly",  //ERROR LINE
        "LNAME" => "Roger",
    ]),
  ]);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "api-key: ****",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ));
```

But it still don't work, ive got this error : 
`Array to string conversion` 
+ this one :
`{"error":{"status":400,"message":"Input must be a valid JSON object","code":"bad_request"}}`

The documentation say that attributes must be an object so i really don't know how to do this. The documentation is really good, but they missed something here... (no exemple)

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, it's just a matter of adding it to the POST fields from `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. However trying to manipulate a JSON-encoded string for anything more than a few simple true/false declarations gets messy really quickly, especially when doing 3d arrays and worrying about escaping quotes in PHP. I would recommend instead you use a PHP array to simplify things, which will also make it easier to include the `attributes` field in your POST request.

**Edit:** From the error message returned from the remote server, it looks like the their API requires the POST data to be sent as a JSON object instead of the standard `'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'` format, so you just need to JSON encode the entire POST array to create a single JSON encoded object:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([
    'email' => 'testCreateContact@test.com',
    'emailBlacklisted' => true,
    'smsBlacklisted' => false,
    'listIds' => [2],
    'updateEnabled' => true,
    'attributes' => [
        'FNAME' => 'Elly',
        'LNAME' => 'Roger',
    ],
]));
```

or if you want to use `curl_setopt_array()`, you could do it like this:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
        'email' => 'testCreateContact@test.com',
        'emailBlacklisted' => true,
        'smsBlacklisted' => false,
        'listIds' => [2],
        'updateEnabled' => true,
        'attributes' => [
            'FNAME' => 'Elly',
            'LNAME' => 'Roger',
        ],
    ]),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'accept: application/json',
        'api-key: *****',
        'content-type: application/json'
    ),
));
```

Comment: So ive tried, and i have a different error : ```Array to string conversion``` on ```curl_setopt_array ( )```. I guess a can't mix your solution and my old code.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that work :

````
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"attributes\":{\"NOM\":\"james\"},\"email\":\"testCreateContact@test.com\",
  \"emailBlacklisted\":false,\"smsBlacklisted\":false,\"listIds\":[2],\"updateEnabled\":true}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "api-key: ****",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));```

Thx
````